# SOLR - IndexOutOfBoundsException ERROR

Tags: solr

I am running SOLR, everything was fine but today suddenly i start getting following error.

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 74, Size: 38 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1103) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this? We are running SOLR for many live sites. But search is down at the moment for all the sites.

Comment: AS it mentions .. Check your log files for more detailed information. There is something wrong with the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My indexing was corrupted, i re-indexed and the problem is solved.